# Should I have been given a badge for incompetence?

Tags: discussion, badges

I recently answerered a question on SO without having digested it fully. On realising that my answer was total hogwash, I hovered over the `delete` link but the hint `vote to delete this post` put me off. I didn't want it to be put to a vote. I then edited the question and attempted to delete the text. This failed since the answer text is a required field. So I overwrote my answer with a short apology and posted it.
Still not happy, I clicked the `delete` link anyway and mercifully the answer vanished, saving my embarrassment.

I'm amazed to find that I've become the recipient of a shiny new editor's badge.

Comment: Even better, they give badges to people (Peer Pressure) who realize that people think they are incompetent and then delete their answers. :)

Comment: Check out the strunk and white badge if you really want a reward for editing.

Comment: (+1) funny story, great delivery.

Comment: We should be giving more badges out to people who realize on their own that they are incompetent. That would be great.

Comment: @TheTXI: "giving answer that is total hogwash" != "incompetent", right?.

Comment: Mark Harrison: I was speaking in general terms, not towards this particular OP.

Comment: txi: you're a moderator now (congrats btw!), so just be aware it comes off unpleasantly when moderators chat in such cavalier terms about the incompetents on their site.

Answer (score 11):

Editor's badge is pretty tame and is just given to anybody who has gone about editing posts. It is not something that is repetitious and more or less just signifies that you are capable of using a certain feature of the system. It is a reward for system usage, not for your knowledge.

**Badges Rewarded For System Usage**

- Autobiographer - fill out your profile
- Citizen Patrol - first flagged post (offensive or spam, not moderator flags)
- Civic Duty - Voted 300 times
- Clean Up - Performed first rollback of a post.
- Commentator - Leave 10 comments
- Critic -  cast First downvote
- Editor - First edit to a post
- Organizer - First retag of a question
- Scholar - Awarded the first time you accept an answer on your question
- Strunk & White - Edit 100 posts
- Supporter - Cast first upvote
- Student - Asked a question and received your first upvote
- Taxonomist - Create a tag that was used 50 times
- Yearling - Active for a year

All the other badges are generally rewards for exceptional contributions (such as getting voted up X amount of times, etc.)

Comment: +1 There are some badges that are simply awards for finding the function. A bit like hidden areas in some games. But easier to achieve.